# Orionjs - Example blog - users not able to update any of the attributes in the post

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, content-management-system

I am trying out the `blog` example in orionjs CMS package of meteor available here - https://github.com/orionjs/examples.

In the example, community users are able to create/delete (their own) posts, however they are not able to update any of the attributes of the post.

According to `orion/roles/community.js`, users should be able to update any attribute other than createdBy

```
/**
 * Users can update posts
 */
CommunityRole.allow('collections.posts.update', function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
  return doc.createdBy === userId; // Will be allowed to edit his own posts
});

/**
 * Users can't change the createdBy attribute
 */
CommunityRole.deny('collections.posts.update', function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
  return !_.contains(fields, 'userId');
});
```

Have raised the same issue in github also - https://github.com/orionjs/examples/issues/16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the original code which has been fixed by the orion creator. In `orion/roles/community.js`, this needs to be changed

```
return !_.contains(fields, 'userId');
```

to

```
return _.contains(fields, 'userId');
```